# White Screen using navigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have to views which should be loaded depending on a return value. This is my code. After building the screen of the simulator stays white. Do you have suggestions what i should change. The logInView and createNewPasswordView are working. If I make them to the rootViewController of the window I can see them

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease]; 
PasswordHandling *aPasswortHandler = [[PasswordHandling alloc] init]; 
self.passwordHandling = aPasswortHandler; [aPasswortHandler release]; 
UINavigationController *navigationController;
if ([passwordHandling passwordInKeyChain] == TRUE) { 
    LogInView *logInView = [[[LogInView alloc] initWithNibName: @"LogInView" bundle: nil] autorelease]; 
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:logInView];
} else { 
     CreateNewPasswordView *createNewPasswordView = [[CreateNewPasswordView alloc] initWithNibName:@"CreateNewPasswordView" bundle: nil]; 
     navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:createNewPasswordView];

}

[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view]; 
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; return YES;
```

i noticed that the MainWindow.Xib is loaded. But that is not the xib file which should be loaded

Comment: If `[passwordHandling passwordInKeyChain]` is a boolean, then `if ([passwordHandling passwordInKeyChain] == TRUE) {` can be replaced with `if ([passwordHandling passwordInKeyChain]) {`

Comment: yeah your right but usually i write the == TRUE to be sure whats done

Comment: You can also change [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view]; to self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;.  You also should release the navigationController after you have added it to the window.  Also try and call NSLog(@"%@", navigationController); in your if statement to see if the UINavigationController is getting created.

Comment: Do not test booleans against `TRUE`. There are many true values that do not `== TRUE`. If anything, you'd want to test for `!= FALSE` (which at least actually means what it says), but that's just crazy. Treat booleans as booleans.

Comment: changed like you suggested, but changed nothing (tried it also befor) and the log says: <UINavigationController: 0x68902d0> i guess this means, that it is created

Comment: Do you have a UIWindow in your MainWindow.xib?

Comment: yes, see the (edited) question. Actually the Main Window is the loaded window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you programmatically creating your window in a project that has a nib file? Nib files are the correct solution to this kind of problem, and since you're using them anyway, there's no good reason to avoid the most basic one.

That said, the first thing you should do is replace this:

```
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

With this:

```
[self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
```

To debug your issues, you should check the frames of all the views you care about. I likely cause of this issue is that at least one of your frames is `CGRectZero`.

** EDIT **

It's not a problem that the VCs have their own nib files. The problem is that you should be using the window created by MainWindow.xib. Especially if you're new, there is no reason you should be creating your window in code. Remove your creation of the window, make sure that self.window is not nil at the point you're running this code, and use setRootViewController rather than addSubview.

Comment: the viewControllers have their own nib Files. I hope thats not the problem. But im a neewbe so tell me if I am wrong. And as an result of that can you tell me how i can check the frames?