# Blank screen after splash on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

One user has sent an e-mail saying that when launching an ipad app he sees splash screen and than statusBar becomes visible and after that there is only blank screen. So he can't proceed with an app. User has iPad3 with iOS 5.1.1. I have tested all possible iOS versions and different usage scenarios, but can't reproduce the situation. Any ideas?

Launching code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    self.window.rootViewController = padMainNavigationController;
}
else
{
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
}
NSError *sessionError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&sessionError];

// 2. Changing the default output audio route
UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker, sizeof(doChangeDefaultRoute), &doChangeDefaultRoute);
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
int cacheSizeMemory = 4*1024*1024; // 4MB
int cacheSizeDisk = 60*1024*1024; // 60MB
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cacheSizeMemory diskCapacity:cacheSizeDisk diskPath:@"nsurlcache"] autorelease];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];

return YES;
}
```

Comment: where is padMainNavigationController instantiated?

Comment: It is connected in interface builder.

Comment: a blank screen indicates that padMainNavigationController is nil, or doesn't have a view connected to it

Comment: It is connected and it is not nil when printed out with nslog. App works on other devices except this one. I can't test on this ipad as it is user's own, but he just said that it is jailbroken device. Can it be the reason?

Comment: test on iPad Simulator, you should be able to reproduce the problem there

Answer (score 1):

See [White Screen using navigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422658/white-screen-using-navigationcontroller) - it solved my problem which was similar to what was described in the OP.